# Can you use the 'setter' from useState inside a condition?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know that the general principle is to [avoid using hooks inside a loop, condition, or nested function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) however in regards to setting state, is it ok to do something like this?

```
function myComponent() {
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState();
  ...
  const nestedFunction = () => {
    if (condition) {
      setMyVar(value);
    }
  }
}
```

If not, how can I accomplish this using Hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is completely fine. The setter is not a hook. `useState` is the only "hook" in your example.

Comment: Ah, so only the `useX` parts are the hooks, which I should follow the rules for. Any of its properties can be used freely. Thanks for the answer!